# Getting an error in terminal as: input file '.\a.exe' is same as output file collect2.exe: error: Id returned 1 exit status

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
// This is my first time!
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    printf("Hello World\n");
    return 0;
}
```

This is my first code and I'm getting this error every time I try to run in Terminal:

```
PS C:\C> gcc .\main2.c
PS C:\C> gcc .\a.exe
C:/Program Files/…/ld.exe: input file './\a.exe' is the same as output file
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
PS C:\C>
```

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W1ixl.png)

Comment: How are you trying to compile it?

Comment: gcc .\main2.c
//This is how I compile. An executable file 'a.exe' is created and then I try to run it.
gcc .\a.exe 
//and then this error occurs. If I change the name of the executable file theneverything goes haywire and the programme still doesn't work.

Comment: Ideally, since you use neither `argc` nor `argv` in the `main()` function, you'd use `int main(void)` instead of what you've got.  However, that's got nothing to do with the problem you're seeing.  Your claimed command line seems unlikely to produce the error you're seeing.  Are you sure that's what you're typing to the command line?  You could probably drop the ```.\``` without causing trouble — but it is far from clear that it would fix anything, either.  Consider running: `gcc -o b.exe main2.c` — does that produce the same error, or an analogous error?  Then run `.\b.exe` if it works.

Comment: hmm... but this is happening with every other code i wrote...

Comment: Then it seems that there is something screwy with your compiler setup.  And since we don't have your machine available, it is going to be hard to guess what is going wrong.  Is there an executable such as `gcc.exe` in the current directory? Or a command script with the base name `gcc` somewhere?  Does the file `a.exe` currently exist?  Given the `.exe` extensions, you're presumably running on Windows rather than a Unix-like system.  Are you using WSL?

Comment: I did. Got a big error as: first defined here  collect2.exe: error: Id returned 1 exit status....I'm running Windows

Comment: "Id" is probably meant to be "Ld" - a linker error.

Comment: You're trying to **run** the compiled program with gcc? Don't do that. Just `./a.exe`

Comment: When I went to edit the question, I found the link to your command — I'm not sure whether it was available when I first looked.  But @Shawn has it exactly right.  You compile with `gcc`; you don't run with `gcc` — you simply run the executable it produced.  Hence: `gcc main2.c` (which worked and created `a.exe`) followed by `.\a.exe` (no further mention of GCC).

Answer (score 1):

```
PS C:\C> gcc .\main2.c
```

This call above created `a.exe` as executable program, you can run it by just running `a`.

```
PS C:\C> gcc .\a.exe
C:/Program Files/…/ld.exe: input file './\a.exe' is the same as output file
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Here, you tried to compile your executable into `a.exe` again, so the compiler is telling you that your input file (the source code, this time `.\a.exe`) and the executable binary (`.\a.exe`) are both the same file (`gcc` doesn't want to trash your input source file --despite it is not such a source file-- by just overwritting it)

To run the program, just:

```
PS C:\C> a
(your program output will go here)
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a file named main2.c

```
// The file named main2.c

#include <stdio.h>
// This is my first time!
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    printf("Hello World\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Open a terminal, then use `cd` changed to the path where the current file(main2.c) is located.

In terminal compile the file use below command:

```
gcc -o main2 main.c
```

Now have generated a executable program that named `main2.exe`. Explanation `-o` specify the name of the generated executable program.

Then type main2.exe (or main2) in terminal, you will see the output "Hello World".

```
main2.exe
```

Suggest use visual studio 2022 on windows system or use Linux system, such as Ubuntu.